# Ctrl-C on DataGridView displays junk characters when pasting

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, clipboard

I have experiencing a strange issue when copying cell data from `DataGridView`.  I have a `ContextMenuStrip` that includes an option to copy a specific field. When they select this option from the Menu, the value copy/pastes exactly as it should.

My code to copy to the Clipboard:

```
public static void CopyToClipboard(string value)
{
   Clipboard.Clear();
   Clipboard.SetText(value);
}
```

If I take this value and paste it into any other app and the value is correct.

My issue comes into play, if I select a cell in the `DataGridView` and use the Keys `Ctrl-C` to copy to the clipboard.  The value that is copied to the clipboard displays correctly in word, notepad, excel but we have an internal application that we try to paste the value into and it has turned into a jumbled mess of characters.

My value copied will be `12345678` and the result in this other app becomes `-§-ý-:pC|yV-k²-û`

I have tried to create a `KeyDown` event on the `DataGridView` that will verify it is a `Ctrl-C` that is keyed and then call my copy to clipboard code but the same thing happens with the values.

```
private void DataGridView_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
   if (e.Control && e.KeyCode == Keys.C)   
      CopyToClipboard(DataGridView2.CurrentCell.Value.ToString());
}
```

If I use a `CellEnter` event and call the copy to clipboard, it works fine, but I would prefer not to copy to clipboard each time a cell is entered..  It seems like the issue is directly with the `Ctrl-C` keys.

```
private void DataGridView_CellEnter(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    CopyAccountToClipboard(DataGridView2.CurrentCell.Value.ToString());
}
```

Has anyone had an issue like this?  Any suggestions on how to fix it?

Comment: So you're saying that both a plain Ctrl+C of a data cell as well as the `KeyDown`+`Clipboard.SetText` comes out jumbled in that app?

Comment: Yes that is what I am saying.

Comment: The obvious question is then: is it also jumbled when you copy _from_ notepad _into_ that internal application?

Comment: No, if I add it to notepad and then copy from notepad to the internal app, it works fine.

Comment: I would try the following then: invoke Clipboard.SetText in your app, passing it a fixed string (rather than CurrentCell.Value) and various TextDataFormat values. If that works, try the same format with CurrentCell. Perhaps CurrentCell.Value.ToString() is itself jumbled?. If that doesn't work, try Clipboard.SetText from a completely blank project; perhaps this has nothing to do with your current app at all.

Comment: Try assigning the value in DataGridView2.CurrentCell.Value.ToString() to a variable to see if it is mangled before you place it in the clipboard.

Comment: I have assigned the value to the a variable and it does display correctly, it is not jumbled.  It only becomes jumbled in the other internal application.

Comment: What version of .net are you using? I had some trouble with non-unicode characters in clipboard in all versions before 4.0, so if you are using earlier versions this could be worth trying

Comment: then try 4.0 and tell if it works. I can only say that Clipboard class is differently implemented in 4.0, so it is worth to try.

Comment: unfortunately, I cannot change to .NET 4.0.

Comment: I can say only unfortunately, Clipboard class in 3.5 has some bugs and you might encounter them. So if that is the case, and it is likely, you can only do some Interop to work around it.

Answer (score 3):

My guess is that your other application is not able to handle Unicode. Try altering your method to set the text in ANSI format:

```
public static void CopyToClipboard(string value)
{
   Clipboard.Clear();
   Clipboard.SetText(value, TextDataFormat.Text);
}
```

**Edit**: Then my second guess would be that `DataGridView` copies text in multiple formats when `Ctrl+C` is pressed, and your other application is getting confusing by the presence of formats it isn’t expecting.

Could you try adding a button to your form which executes the following logic when clicked?

```
string text = Clipboard.GetText(TextDataFormat.Text);
Clipboard.Clear();
Clipboard.SetText(text, TextDataFormat.Text);
```

Then try:

1. Copying your cell to the clipboard using `Ctrl+C`
2. Clicking the said button
3. Pasting the text in your other application

Don’t test the above code in your `DataGridView_KeyDown` event handler (yet).